# Tag synonym: grammer → grammar

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

There is an unused tag [[grammer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammer)], which must be a misspelling for [[grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar)].  Moderators or anyone with enough rep, please make [grammer] a tag synonym for [grammar].

Comment: I don't see this tag anywhere (new question form, tag list, etc.) It may already have been deleted.

Comment: @Bruno: Hmm, I do not either, so there is no need for action anymore.  Thanks for the comment.  Do you know what I should do with this question?  Should I delete it, or vote to close?

Comment: I think you can just post an answer saying that nothing needs to be done an accept it.

Comment: @Bruno: Done.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, it's alive in this post: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56674/i-would-like-to-know-how-this-clause-as-written-would-be-interpreted

Comment: The misspelling "grammer" is horrible. Why has it not been deleted?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag seems to have been already deleted (automatically?), and nothing has to be done about it.  Thank you to Bruno Rothgiesser for pointing it out!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

It hasn’t been deleted: the [grammer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammer) tag is now a synonym for the correctly spelled [grammar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar) tag.

There is, however, no [glamour](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glamour) tag.